# React Tranisition group Transition animation not working on exiting

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

Transition animation works on entering based on height, but on exiting animaiton doesn't work.
Initial height is '0px' and on **entering** changed height to wrapper height then on **entered** state height is set to 'auto'. Transition animation works here.

Before **exit**, again height is set to wrapper height, then on **exiting** height changed to '0px'.Transition animation doesn't work here.

But it works, when breakpoint set on **onExit** method.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-grass-gp6v9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: do u want to have same transition on exiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the exiting transition style height to auto, the transition is now working as expected.

```
const transitionStyle = {
    entered: { height: "auto", overflow: "visible" },
    exiting: { height: "auto" }  /*change this */
  };
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. But now the animation works only on exited state, hence there is a delay in toggle click.

Comment: If we are setting height dynamically when trying to show a content, we should also let the transition do the calculation for us from the 'defaultStyle' object we already assign height to be 0